# Как сделать алгоритм теста?

Tags: javascript

Делаю одну задачу, суть такая:
Пользователь вводит термины в input, они сохраняются в localStorage, после этого пользователь должен ответить знает он этот термин, или может объяснить, либо пропустить термин. Не могу разобраться как сделать правильно алгоритм работы

[image: Интерфейс]

```
window.onload = function() {
  const input = document.querySelector("#name-form6-5");
  let save = document.getElementById('save');
  
  save.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let arr = input.value;
    let array = arr.split(' ')
    localStorage.setItem('value', JSON.stringify(array));
    window.location.reload();
  })

  const paragraph = document.getElementById("question");
  score = 0;
  const arrayOfStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('value'))
  console.log(arrayOfStorage)
  
  for (let i = 0; i < JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('value')).length; i++) {
    paragraph.innerText = arrayOfStorage[0];
    document.querySelector('#understand').addEventListener('click', function() {
      score += 1;
      paragraph.innerText = arrayOfStorage[i + 1];
   }) 
  }
}
```

```
<section class="hidden">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="mbr-section-head">
                <h3 class="mbr-section-title mbr-fonts-style align-center mb-0 display-2"><strong>Выберите
                        ответ:</strong></h3>
                <p id="question" class="mbr-fonts-style mbr-text mbr-white mb-3 display-7">
                    Вопросы отобразятся здесь</p>
                <div id="buttons">
                    <button type="submit" id="understand" class="btn btn-primary display-4">Понимаю</button>
                    <button type="submit" id="know" class="btn btn-primary display-4">Умею</button>
                    <button type="submit" id="skip" class="btn btn-primary display-4">Пропустить</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Проблема у Вас конкретно с чем?

Comment: С тем как реализовать такой алгоритм. Как я думаю:
Пользователю дается первый вопрос (test на скрине), он нажимает на кнопку ответа, если отвечает понимаю (Может объснить) - в score добавляется 1, за ответ умею в score добавляется 2, за пропустить не добавляется ничего. После ответов считается максимально возможное количество баллов (например 10 терминов - максимум 20 баллов), и если у пользователя такое же количество (100%), то оценка отлично, если 12 правильных (60%), то хорошо, если 10 и ниже то неуд. Вот с реализацией этого алгоритма проблема

Comment: @XelaNimed сейчас проблема со счетчиком
Мне выводит в консоли 0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15 при одном нажатии на кнопку, хотя должно добавляться 1

Comment: 1. Эту информацию нужно поместить в вопрос, а не в комментарий (в таком случае в комментарии указать "обновил вопрос"). 2. Чем/как собираетесь тестировать или при чём здесь тест? Или я чего-то недопонимаю? Консоль и дебуггер в браузере? 3. Так пользователю даётся термин или он его вводит сам через текстовое поле? В вопросе у Вас одно, а в комментарии другое. P.S.: чтоб Ваш вопрос был понятен и полезен, в будущем старайтесь как можно развёрнутей описывать Вашу задачу/проблему/исходные и исходящие данные. В любом случае поясняющую информацию лучше добавлять в вопрос.